# MapReduce distributed reducer

Tags: java, mapreduce, distributed, counting, mapper

Just started learning MapReduce and I have a file where there are an actor and a movie he played in (per line). I want to create a file as follows:

```
actor     movie1, movie2, ..., movieN
```

i.e. a key - value file but only one line appearance of an actor and all his movies. This is no problem.

After I have this file created I want to find the actor with most movies played in as a second MR - Job. I read my new file (output of the previous Job) and simply replace (in `map()`) the movies with the number. In my Reducer I just have to compare with previous result

```
if(numberOfRoles.get() < sum){
        numberOfRoles.set(sum);
        actorWithMostRoles.set(key);
}
```

where *numberOfRoles* and *actorWithMostRoles* are attributes of the Reducer - Class.

This works without any problems.

My output of **jps**:

```
$ jps
32347 Jps
25323 DataNode
25145 NameNode
25541 SecondaryNameNode
```

I know that there can be multiple Mapper & Reducer. For example Reducer_0 and Reducer_1 which will output the actor with the most movies played in. Having following data:

> actor1    movie1, movie2, movie3
>   actor2    movie4, movie5

So Reducer_0 will get actor1 to count and thus output **actor1 3** and Reducer_1 will output **actor2 2**. So I will have two lines instead of one (actor1) - because each Reducer has found the actor.

After I have described my doing I have following question:

Either I don't understand how it works (with multiple reducer - in a cluster) or I have to do synchronisation somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you understand how it works.

You will need another map reduce job to finish it up for you in this setup.

or, just use a single reducer and be done with it!

Answer (score 0):

In the second MR Job read your new file (output of the previous Job)
and change your MR to like this below

**Mapping Phase :**
Read each actor and their movie count and output it with a special key "max" and value pair of actor name and their movie count like this one

```
output key = "max"  
output value = ("actor", movieCount)
```

**Reducing Phase :**
You will get all of the actor and his movie count as value list in a single reducer so just find the max movie count from the value list

```
input key = "max"   
input value = [("actor",movie_count), ("actor",movie_count) ...]   
output key = "most movies played"      
output value = max_value
```